# Why can I not display a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am a PHP newbie and I am learning PHP off a book but I can not display a two-dimensional array using echo variable. Every time I try it always throws back this error, **Warning**: Uninitialized string offset 2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php** on line **19**. As I said I do not know what this means I have searched but it still does not display.
My code

```
<?php //test1.php
echo $lang[2]; //Displays Javascript not CSS reason above
$ttt = array(
            array('x', '', 'o'),
            array('o', 'o', ''),
            array('x', 'o', '')
            ); //you can stack arrays like this
echo $ttt[0][1][2]; //displaying tick tack toe
?>
```

line 19 is `echo $ttt[0][1][2]; //displaying tick tack toe`

Comment: You have a two-dimensional array, but you're trying to access a _third_ dimension. Since `$ttt[0][1]` is a string PHP interprets this third dimension as a byte offset of 2 in the empty string `''`, but the string is not that long, hence the error.

Comment: I do not understand what does "Since $ttt[0][1] is a string PHP interprets this third dimension as a byte offset of 2 in the string 'o', but the string is not that long, hence the error." means

Comment: Wait, are you trying to print the entire tic-tac-toe grid with `echo $ttt[0][1][2];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there This is only a double so don't need all three just use

```
echo $ttt[0][2];
```

If you want to echo out the whole Tic Tack Toe you will need to echo each value like this

```
    echo "<table><tr><td>{$ttt[0][0]}</td><td>{$ttt[0][1]}</td><td>{$ttt[0][2]}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{$ttt[1][0]}</td><td>{$ttt[1][1]}</td><td>{$ttt[1][2]}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{$ttt[2][0]}</td><td>{$ttt[2][1]}</td><td>{$ttt[2][2]}</td></tr></table>"; //displaying tick tack toe
```

Don't forget in programing we start at 0

Comment: I tried that but It just displayed a "o"

Comment: That's what should happen because you echoing the third value of the first array, please note we start always at 0

Comment: I understand now I watched a video and looked at your problem and fixed it.